# Serial monitor font arduino can't show

Tags: arduino, serial-monitor

Hello my serial monitor font is get trouble, i can't fix it, anybody knows ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2SeF.png)

Comment: set a baud rate which matches the baud rate in the sketch

Answer (score 1):

Either the sending device is sending non-sense or non-ASCII data or (more likely) you have a baud rate mismatch.

The serial interface you're using here is asynchronous. That means there is no common clock to synchronize communication. Hence the receiving side must know the baud rate of the sender or vice versa. If you're sampling the Rx line with the wrong frequency you don't recieve what has been sent but more or less random characters.

Alter the baud rate setting until you read the correct data.

Give this a read

https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/serial-communication/all  it explains serial communication for beginners.